# FIrebase AuthStateListener is not getting called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to call AuthStateListener for firebase user login using firebase UI but the method is not called when activity is executed. I have done the same process before for various applications Here is the code:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In SignedinFirebaseMethod");

            } else {
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setProviders(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER,
                                        AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER)
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the Gradle Code:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hamid_pc.auctionapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post your app module build.gradle file.

Comment: @BobSnyder I have updated the code and included the gradle code

Comment: I don't see a problem there.  Does your device have a compatible version of Google Play Services installed?  Do you see `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date` message in the logcat when your app initializes?

Comment: @BobSnyder No error displayed in logcat

Comment: I am getting this statement : DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. Any suggestion @BobSnyder

Comment: I'm pretty sure that warning is not significant.  I see it frequently in an app where auth operations work correctly.I don't know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

try to register the listener before doing the auth with firebase. It can be possible that you are attaching listener late.

**abstract void onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth auth)**

This method gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the authentication state:

- Right after the listener has been registered
- When a user is signed in
- When the current user is signed out When the current user changes

Comment: I don't think registering the listener is the issue

Comment: can you show the flow in activity, at what point the firebaseauth.signin is called

Comment: The method is called in OnCreate method and the code is above

Comment: I have used the the same method as it is mentioned in the code   @UmarHussain

Comment: Then it can be a firebase configuration problem, was it working earlier for you in this same application?

Comment: I was using same method in other application but not this project check all possibilities of error

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error in the code I was not attaching listener when starting the fragment

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
```